# From a function outside how would I access a variable inside the render function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I am trying to figure out how to access a variable declared inside render from a function that is outside render, I do not fully understand how to go about doing this because I am very new to React-Native and I believe solving this one thing will give me a good understand of how scope works in this language. For my project I access user data through this.props, however when I try to pass this data to an outside function it seems to fail with what I assume has to do with scope. I simplified my code just to the parts that matter, pagination is the function outside of render() when I try to access the variable indicator declared in render it cannot find the variable. I am getting user data from this.props. Thank you in advance!

```
get pagination () {

length = indicator
}

        render () {
                const { wrap,image, images, auto, button, indicator} = this.props
return(
<View>
{ this.pagination }
</View> 
)}
```

Comment: You're trying to pass/access data from one component to another? Could you please past share snippets of the relevant components

Answer (score 0):

Remember that variables are only accessible inside of their scope (curly brackets). Because you are declaring `indicator` inside the render scope, it will only be accessible there. If you want `pagination` to have access to it, you'll need to pass it as a function argument.

For example:

```
pagination(indicator) {
 // Do something with indicator
 return "Page " + indicator
}

render() {

  const { indictator } = this.props;
  return (<View>
    { this.pagination(indicator) }
  </View>); 

}
```